# Why background color is not applying to DIV container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply background color over the DIV element. Since the DIV's children are floating left, I assume both the children are in the DIV container.

But If I add position: absolute to DIV container, I could see the result as expected. But still, I don't understand it, what difference does it makes with absolute position.

```
<style>
        span {
          float: left;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        div {
          border: 1px solid #ccc;
          background-color: yellow;
          left: 200px;
        }

</style>
<div>
    <span>Span A</span>
    <span>Span B</span>
</div>
```

Comment: for the position:absolute part it's here : *Floats, absolutely positioned elements, block containers (such as inline-blocks, table-cells, and table-captions) that are not block boxes, and block boxes with 'overflow' other than 'visible' (except when that value has been propagated to the viewport) establish new block formatting contexts for their contents.* https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting .. so it's like `overflow:hidden` it establish a new **block formatting contexts** (you can make the div float also and it will work lik position:absolute)

Comment: ^ in the duplicates you will find many answer talking about **block formatting contexts** which is the key of clearing float (in addtion to the clear property)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It really helped me. But, this question doesn't seems to be duplicate of the one you have marked it. My question was with respect to position: absolute;

Comment: the duplicate are more generic and explain the clear thing. Position:absolute is one particular case, so I think better understand this in general than simply one case.

Answer (score 3):

In your case you floated them to `float:left`, you didn't apply `height` for that`<div>`. I would suggest you to use `display:inline-block` for `<span>` so that they will be aligned inline with block size. No need to use floats in this case

> By default `span` has `display:inline` property

Using floats.Solution for your code.

```css
span {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 200px;
  height:100px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span A</span>
  <span>Span B</span>
</div>
```

You can do this using `display:inline-block` rather than using `float`

```css
span {
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 200px;

}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span A</span>
  <span>Span B</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your div has a background color, but because the spans have a `float` set, their parent doesn't take their width/height: it now has no width and height.

Instead of `float: left`, you probably wanted to use: `display: inline-block` on the `span` elements. Like so:

```css
span {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span A</span>
  <span>Span B</span>
</div>
```

Another solution is to give the parent div the property `display: table`. Because the parent will then get the width/height of it's children (unless it's absolutely positioned). Like so:

```css
span {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Span A</span>
  <span>Span B</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your wonderful explanation. I was just trying to know the logic behind this.

Comment: You're welcome. It's also useful to know the default "browser styles" of elements. `display: inline` is the default style for `<p>` elements. You can simply check this with your browser's Developer Tools. Click on the element, go to the "Computed" styles tab and make sure "Browser styles" or "Show all" is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Remove float left from span as the span tag is of display: inline by default and there is no fixed width applied for span.

```
<style>

    span {
      padding: 10px;
    }
    div {
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      background-color: yellow;
      left: 200px;
    }

</style>

    <div>
      <span>Span A</span>
      <span>Span B</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the height and width attribute for div tag

```css
<style>

span {
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: yellow;
  left: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px
}

</style>
```

```html
  <div>
    <span>Span A</span>
    <span>Span B</span>
  </div>
```